# XPath for radio button (option) with question text (title)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

Here's what the relevant part of my DOM looks like:

```
<div class="questions" xpath="1">
<div class="question">
   <div class="section-name">General Knowledge</div>
   <div class="title" style="">Which of these cities is the capital of India?</div>
   <span class="description">Some description text</span>
   <div class="options">
      <div class="mui-radio"><label for="x7xvolm-116"><input id="x7xvolm-116" type="radio" value="116" style=""><span class="option-text">Mumbai</span></label></div>
      <div class="mui-radio"><label for="x7xvolm-117"><input id="x7xvolm-117" type="radio" value="117"><span class="option-text">Delhi</span></label></div>
      <div class="mui-radio"><label for="x7xvolm-118"><input id="x7xvolm-118" type="radio" value="118"><span class="option-text">Kolkata</span></label></div>
      <div class="mui-radio"><label for="x7xvolm-119"><input id="x7xvolm-119" type="radio" value="119"><span class="option-text">Chennai</span></label></div>
      <div class="mui-radio"><label for="x7xvolm-120"><input id="x7xvolm-120" type="radio" value="120"><span class="option-text">Bengaluru</span></label></div>
      <div class="mui-radio"><label for="x7xvolm-121"><input id="x7xvolm-121" type="radio" value="121"><span class="option-text">Nagpur</span></label></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to come up with an XPath that would have two arguments which would help me select the required option from Selenium code:

1. Question title (`Which of these cities is the capital of India?`)
2. Option label (`Delhi`)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: You didn't add any new information. What did you try? what was the problem with it? you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The fact that this question has a sufficient amount of details is evident from the fact that there are 4 answers already, which implies that the contributors have understood it.

PS: I did edit the question. Also, I did not try with anything as I have no idea as to how I could deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer assumes [Selenium Java Client Bindings](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/):

```
String question = "Which of these cities is the capital of India?"; 
String answer = "Delhi";                                            
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()= '" + question + "']" +   
        "/parent::*/div[@class='options']/descendant::*" +          
        "/span[text()='" + answer + "']")).click();
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 1):

```
.//\*[contains(text(),'Which of these cities is the capital of India?')]//following-sibling::div//\*[contains(text(),'Delhi')]
```

Try with this. Hopefully, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following xpath to access `radio` button.

```
//div[@class="title"][contains(.,"Which of these cities is the capital of India?")]/following-sibling::div[@class="options"]//span[contains(.,"Delhi")]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

OR

```
//div[@class="title"][contains(.,"Which of these cities is the capital of India?")]/following-sibling::div[@class="options"]//span[contains(.,"Delhi")]/preceding-sibling::input
```

Comment: Just another option `//div[normalize-space(.)='Which of these cities is the capital of India?']/following-sibling::div[@class='options']//input[following-sibling::span[.='Delhi']]`.

Answer (score 1):

To identify the required option with Question title as **Which of these cities is the capital of India?** and option label as **Delhi** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//div[@class='title' and text()='Which of these cities is the capital of India?']//following::div[1]//label[span[@class='option-text' and text()='Delhi']]
```